# Wrong date react native calendars

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

I'm using react-native-calendars library to implement calendar in my app. I found the problem that calendar shows wrong date.

[image: Calendar]

As you can see on screen it shows Wednesday 31th but it should be Tuesday 31th.

Comment: Use `firstDay` prop to control which day is the first day of the week. See [here](https://wix.github.io/react-native-calendars/docs/Components/Calendar#firstday). Please post your related code if this doesn't work,

Comment: It works, thanks!